# Find all permutations with reversals / cyclic permutations removed

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation, canonicalization

I have a list of all non-cyclic permutations of n labels. How can I  get rid of all elements which are redundant in the sense that they are the inverse of another one. For instance if n=4, the elements {1,2,3,4} and {1,4,3,2} are related by reversal and right rotation by one element. So I want to discard the latter.

Cheers!

Comment: `DeleteDuplicates[
 Permutations[Range[4]], #1 == InversePermutation[#2] &]`?

Comment: If I use DeleteDuplicates[ Permutations[Range[4]], #1 == RotateRight[Reverse[#2]] &] it works, i.e. it kills all the entries which are the same under inversion :) For some reason InversePermutation does not do the trick.

Comment: @kguler: Apparently `InversePermutation[]` only works on `Cycle[]` objects...

Comment: I see ... you meant `reversion and right rotation` - `InversePermutation` is quite unrelated.

Comment: @J.M. that's the impression one gets from the docs; but it works with permutation lists too. You can see this by replacing the `Cycle[]` objects with the associated permutation lists in all the examples in docs, or checking `PermutationProduct[#, InversePermutation[#]]&` with cycles and/or lists as input.

Comment: @kguler Hmm, okay, but if I had the permutation list itself, I'd be using `Ordering[]`...

Comment: @J.M right ... incidentally, many `Permutation`-related functions accept both cycles and lists.

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you want can be done by placing the permutations into a canonical form before running `DeleteDuplicates`, as I explained in [How to represent a list as a cycle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17041/how-to-represent-a-list-as-a-cycle/17042#17042).

Here with the addition of `Reverse`:

```
primaryPermutations[a_List] :=
  Module[{f1, f2},
    f1 = RotateLeft[#, Ordering[#, 1] - 1] &;
    f2 = # ~Extract~ Ordering[#, 1] &[f1 /@ {#, Reverse@#}] &;
    DeleteDuplicates[f2 /@ a]
  ]
```

Use:

```
Permutations @ Range @ 4 // primaryPermutations
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4}}
> ```

A faster approach may be to generate these "primary" permutations directly, then extract those that are present in your list using `Intersection`.