# Delete duplicates when cycle both position and element

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Cycle of **position** means: `{a, b, a, a}` and `{a, a, b, a}` is the same.

Cycle of **element** means: `{a, b, a, a}` and `{b, a, b, b}` is the same.

---

Related: [How to represent a list as a cycle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17041/how-to-represent-a-list-as-a-cycle)

There's a solution of position cycle.

[image]

Notice that $(2)$ and $(3)$ is the same.

$$\rm{BBWBWW} \to \rm{WWBWBB} \to \rm{BBWWBW} = \rm{BBWWBW}$$

So how to delete the duplicates in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[labelings, labelingFreeCanonize]

labelings[a_] := Module[{u = Union @ a}, a /. Map[Thread[u -> #] &] @ Permutations[u]]

labelingFreeCanonize = First @ Sort[canonize /@ labelings[#]] &;

Union[labelingFreeCanonize /@ t]
```

[image]

**FWIW: Alternative ways to *canonize***:

**1.** [`Permute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permute.html) input list under the elements of [`CyclicGroup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CyclicGroup.html):

```
ClearAll[canonizeCG]
canonizeCG = First @ Sort @ Permute[#, CyclicGroup[Length @ #]] &;
```

**2.** Use `Ordering @* Ordering` to get the ranks of list elements instead of `Position` in @Mr.Wizard's `canonize`:

```
ClearAll[ranks, canonize2, canonize3]

ranks = Ordering @* Ordering;

canonize2[a_] := ranks[a] // Map[RotateLeft[a, # - 1] &] // Sort // First
```

or

```
canonize3[a_] := ranks[a] // Map[RotateLeft[a, #1 - 1] &] // #[[First@Ordering[#, 1]]] &
```

All three methods give the same result as `canonize`:

```
canonize /@ t == canonizeCG /@ t == canonize2 /@ t == canonize3 /@ t
```

> True