# Matching and counting reversed pairs in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

Given a list of character pairs like `{{"w", "u"}, {"a", "j"}, {"c", "s"}, {"s", "l"}, ....}`, I would like to group the reversed set pairs and then get a total count for each unique character pair. e.g. `{"w", "u"} and {"u", "w"}` as

```
    SeedRandom[2222];
    a = Partition[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 10000], 2]; 
    b = PositionIndex[a];

    a[[b[{"w", "u"}] \[Union] b[{"u", "w"}] ]]
```

Gives the set

> {{"w", "u"}, {"u", "w"}, {"u", "w"}, {"u", "w"}, {"u", "w"}, {"u", 
>   "w"}, {"u", "w"}, {"w", "u"}, {"w", "u"}, {"w", "u"}, {"w", "u"},
>   {"u", "w"}, {"u", "w"}}

My initial approach was to `Sort` the keys and find the matching reversed pair using

```
   sa = Sort[ Keys[b]];
   If [Position[sa, {#[[2]], #[[1]]}][[1, 1]] >= Position[sa, {#[[1]],#[[2]]}][[1, 1]], 
      {Position[sa, {#[[1]], #[[2]]}][[1, 1]], Position[sa, {#[[2]], #[[1]]}][[1, 1]]},
       Null] & /@ sa
```

to give me the pairs but it fails for cases that do not repeat.  Sure I'm missing an easier way.

Comment: Are you looking for `CountsBy[a, Sort]`?  There's also `GroupBy` and the older corresponding functions `GatherBy` and `Tally`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I am looking for the indexes or set of pairs like the example across all the  of the pair groupings.  From that result I can get the count using `Length /@ %`

Comment: These seem related: [(44)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44/121), [(1302)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1302/121), [(5799)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5799/121),
[(11906)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11906/121),
[(17041)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17041/121)

Comment: @ex-kiwi Did you look at the `GroupBy` function that I also suggested?

Comment: @ Szabolics I see @rhermans beat me to it.  The only other thing I would like is to extract the `PositionIndex` for the pairs which the `GatherBy` does not supply.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @Szabolcs already gave you the answer.

```
SeedRandom[2222];
a = Partition[RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 10000], 2];
GatherBy[a, Sort]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Length /@ GatherBy[a, Sort] === Normal[CountsBy[a, Sort]][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```